# ThinkPad T430 will only boot every other try

Tags: boot, laptop, bios, thinkpad

I have a very strange issue with my ThinkPad T430.

If I try to turn on the computer, the fan and hard disks spin, and the power indicator comes on. However, there is nothing on the screen, and the BIOS doesn't load. (Usually the BIOS generates a beep if you press F1 on startup, but this doesn't happen.)

At this point, I either hold down the power button for a hard poweroff, or unplug the computer and remove the battery. In either case, the computer boots perfectly the second time.

If I then shut down the computer via any method (issuing a shutdown command, unplugging, etc.) the computer will again fail to boot the next time. This cycle repeats, so the boots are only successful on every other powerup.

I am completely perplexed by this behavior, and wondering if anybody has a clue what's happening. The behavior is repeatable no matter how long I wait between powerups, so I don't think it's some transient residual charge in RAM or capacitors.